# JavaFX mp3 playback Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, javafx, mp3, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to play mp3 file in java program using javafx. I installed dependencies `libavcodec53` and `libavformat53` [mentioned here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/system_requirements_2-2/jfxpub-system_requirements_2-2.htm). I used following code

```
  public void play(String path_to_song){
        JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        String song = new File(path_to_song).toURI().toString();
        Media audio =null;
        audio = new Media(song);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(audio);
        mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

But I still got error `"Error media audio format unsupported"`

```
Exception in thread "main" MediaException: MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: "Error media audio format unsupported" : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: "Error media audio format unsupported"
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:125)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:474)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:383)
    at playback.Player.play(Player.java:39)
    at engine.Execute.main(Execute.java:15)
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: "Error media audio format unsupported"
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.MediaUtils.nativeError(MediaUtils.java:331)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMedia.init(GSTMedia.java:50)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMedia.<init>(GSTMedia.java:33)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer.<init>(GSTMediaPlayer.java:39)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTPlatform.prerollMediaPlayer(GSTPlatform.java:100)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.PlatformManager.createMediaPlayer(PlatformManager.java:173)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:264)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:139)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:431)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is not listed as a [supported configuration for Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html), you might want to create a [feature request](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) to get JavaFX to support it.

Comment: I figured so much out, but I was hoping somebody had found some workaround.

Comment: Log the feature request, and in the feature request add a comment asking the developers if they know of any workaround :-)

Comment: This has been resolved for Java8u40, see the similar question: [JavaFX MediaPlayer in Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068631/javafx-mediaplayer-in-ubuntu-14-04-64-bits)

Comment: Solved by patch from Oracle

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068631/javafx-mediaplayer-in-ubuntu-14-04-64-bits