# JavaFx playback of mp3 file in Linux Mint

Tags: javafx, audio

This seems to be a recurring issue:

- [JavaFX mp3 playback Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848752/javafx-mp3-playback-ubuntu-14-04)
- [JavaFX mp3 playback became unsupported in Ubuntu 14.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195853/javafx-mp3-playback-became-unsupported-in-ubuntu-14-10)
- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=178503

After updating from Linux Mint 18 to Linux Mint 20, the creation of `MediaPlayer` for [this file](https://sourceforge.net/p/openpatrician/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/OpenPatrician/OpenPatricianData/src/main/resources/sound/pater-noster.mp3) fails (the locator uri is on the same file system) due to `ERROR_MEDIA_AUDIO_FORMAT_UNSUPPORTED`. Loading a `*.wav` file works though and from that I get this debug output:

```
Debug (0:00:05:544): Creating AudioClip for URI file:/home/.../target/classes/sound/organ.wav
Debug (0:00:05:591): Enabled JFXMedia platforms: 
   - com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.java.JavaPlatform
   - com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTPlatform
Debug (0:00:05:591): JFXMedia supported protocols:
    file
    http
    https

Debug (0:00:05:594): Getting content types from platform: com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.java.JavaPlatform@3a36fa07
Debug (0:00:05:594): Getting content types from platform: com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTPlatform@3e10dcb9
Debug (0:00:05:594): JFXMedia supported content types:
    audio/x-aiff
    audio/mp3
    audio/mpeg
    audio/x-wav
    video/mp4
    audio/x-m4a
    video/x-m4v
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl
    audio/mpegurl
```

The protocol here is `file` and the mime type is `audio/mpeg` which are both in the supported list above. Obviously the platform that is used is GSTPlatform.

As I understand it this is a problem with a missing codec. However I made sure that these libraries are present:

- libavutil56
- libavformat58
- libavcodec58

1. Did I miss a library that is required?
2. Is there a way to have an additional Platform that would work?
3. What needs to be done to change the content type to be recognized as `audio/mp3` instead of `audio/mpeg` and would that possibly solve the issue.

As mentioned above the same code could initialize the player with this file on Linux Mint 18, so it cannot be an issue with the code itself, but must be in the environment.

Java version: openjdk 14.0.1 2020-04-14

JavaFX version: 11

Comment: Can you try the latest JavaFX version (i.e. 14.0.2.1)?

Comment: Still the same error with JavaFX 14.0.2.1

Comment: Try to send an email to openjfx-dev@openjdk.java.net asking if anything changed between versions 18 and 20.

Comment: Also posted this on the Linux Mint forum: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=326535